# How to Update usermeta field for all users on Wordpress?

Tags: sql, wordpress

I have a usermeta field for all users in Wordpress that is set to 'true' and needs to be changed to 'false'.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to change with SQL

```
UPDATE `wp_usermeta` SET `meta_value`= 'false' WHERE meta_key = "_status" and meta_value = 'true'
```